# Back button press on Windows Phone 8.1 Monogame

Tags: monogame, windows-phone-8

I am developing a simple game for windows phone and I got stuck when at the handling the back button press.

I have been searching for a while on google but I have not found anything that could work for me. I have seen a function GamePad but i couldn't find on which namespace is this function located, and if it is working on WP8.1.

So my question is, how can I set up a function in which I can handle some code when user press back button.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466938/windows-phone-xna-game-back-button

Comment: Yes, but when I try to override the the OnNavigatedFrom method on build i get this error:
'Error 1 Game1.GamePage.OnNavigatedFrom(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'Game1.GamePage'

I am using the new Monogame template for windows phone 8.1 which is not silverlight but runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too couldn't wrap my head around this, as there is no mention of it in the documentation whatsoever. I also tried every single thing I could google and in the end, I figured it out by chance.

It's quite simple, really:

```
GamePadState padState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
if (padState.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

**BUT!**

I had some major issues with it for what appeared to be two incomprehensibly related reasons: firstly, be sure to call this in your update as soon as you can. Calling it on the end of my update method made it work only *sometimes* (probably for some other reason, but I couldn't figure it out).

And secondly, keep one global instance of `GamePadState`for use in all classes that might have some control logic - I had two classes that registered control (with their own `GamePadState` instances) and while one did register the back button, the other didn't - and when I "paused" the update of the first one, the second one started to register it. Beats me.